# Visual C# - How to copy files from Resources to a folder in disk when a program is ran?

Tags: c#, process, resources, backgroundworker

I am having trouble creating a simple app in Visual C#, that does the following:

1. Insistently seek for a specific process.
2. When that process starts running, copy a resource to a folder.
3. When the process ends, copy another resource to that folder.

I tried using timers+threads, with no success. I think that a BackgroundWorker would help here, but the documentation is rather unclear. Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ResourceCopyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        BackgroundWorker bw;
        bool pcRunning = false;
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Loop);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            cfgInstall.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.pcLocation;
            cfgLag.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.lag;
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
            Properties.Settings.Default.pcLocation = cfgInstall.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.lag = (int)cfgLag.Value;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        public void Loop(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            pcRunning = false;
            bool pcWasRunning = pcRunning;
            if (pcRunning && !pcWasRunning) {
                MessageBox.Show("Process found");
                pcWasRunning = true;
                Swap(true);
            }
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses()) {
                if (p.ProcessName.Equals("Process")) {
                    pcRunning = true;
                }
            }
            if (!pcRunning && pcWasRunning) {
                MessageBox.Show("Process lost");
                Swap(false);
            }
        }
        public void Swap(bool v) {
            byte[] file;
            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan((long)cfgLag.Value));
            if (v) {
                file = Properties.Resources.NewRes;
            } else {
                file = Properties.Resources.BackupRes;
            }
            string path = cfgInstall.Text;
            if (!cfgInstall.Text.EndsWith("/") && !cfgInstall.Text.EndsWith("\\")) {
                path = cfgInstall.Text + "/test.txt";
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, file);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening, any errors or what functionality isn't working

Comment: Currently your background worker only runs one rather than looping as would be implied by its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your current code only runs the check once and then the BackgroundWorker finishes. You could either:

- use a timer to look for the process intermittently (say every minute), along the lines of the code you currently have in `Loop`. When the process has started, you can then use `Process.WaitForExit()` to pause your code until the process finishes. To continue to have your program be responsive, this part should be in a `BackgroundWorker`. Of course, there is a risk with this method that the process starts and finishes quickly, between timer ticks.
- Use `ManagementEventWatcher` within WMI. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) article on CodeProject defines a class that simplifies using WMI to be notified when a process starts and stops:

  ```
  notePad = new ProcessInfo("notepad.exe");
  notePad.Started +=
      new Win32Process.ProcessInfo.StartedEventHandler(this.NotepadStarted);
  notePad.Terminated +=
      new Win32Process.ProcessInfo.TerminatedEventHandler(this.NotepadTerminated);
  ```

The underlying code they are using is below:

```
  string queryString =
    "SELECT *" +
    "  FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
    "WITHIN  " + pol +
    " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
    "   AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + appName + "'";

  // You could replace the dot by a machine name to watch to that machine
  string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

  // create the watcher and start to listen
  watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
  watcher.EventArrived +=
          new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.OnEventArrived);
  watcher.Start();
```

Comment: I will try this now, and mark your answer as correct if appropriate.

Comment: It worked! Kinda... When I close the program, I get a error/warning in the debugger: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.